# Image-button with css

Tags: html, css, image, button, imagebutton

I would like to learn how to do 'nice buttons' where the picture is added with css. For instance suppose that I want something like the following

[image: nice button]

(that is, the picture and the text are together and the whole picture is the link. You may see http://www.geogebra.org/team for something with the same spirit). The question is to do so as follows

**HTML**

```
<a class="modern_art" href="...">Modern Art</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.modern_art{
     background-image: url(/pictures/modern_art.jpg) 
     /* or something similar */
     /* more instructions */
}
```

By now, the best I have done is to place the picture and afterwards the name with `::before`, but this is not enough to get a nice button. What would you recommend me?

Comment: Why `::before`? The text is inside the `<a>` tag, so you can just position if below or next to the image. Use `padding` to make room for the background image. What is your question?

Comment: Why it must be added `with css`? Why not just put the text and image in `a` tag?

Comment: @Malik Because of accesibility reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [one](https://jsfiddle.net/gdyrrahitis/35m5k2xa/).

In this fiddle you can find something similar to what you ask. Just make an anchor tag as a thumbnail and then put your content inside it. Something like this one:

```
<a href="#" class="thumbnail">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Ce8.png" alt="bg" />
    <figcaption>
      <div>
      Caption here
      </div>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</a>
```

Then I'm using positioning and CSS3 transitions to hide and show the caption.

**UPDATE**

I have updated the code to transition back to the normal state, rather than instantly getting back to it. Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gdyrrahitis/35m5k2xa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Found this, might help you out.

https://css-tricks.com/design-considerations-text-images/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're very close with your CSS. All it needs is an explicit width and height, and some padding.

```css
.modern_art{
     display:inline-block;
     width: 252px; height:20px;
     background: #a9a9a9 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2ZG0.png) no-repeat center 40px;
     padding: 318px 60px 30px;
     text-align:center; /* oh well, and some styling to make the text look similar to the example */
     color:black;
     text-decoration:none;
     font-size:20px;
     letter-spacing:.1em;
}
```

```html
<a class="modern_art" href="...">Modern Art</a>
```